# jQuery - take variable from other function

Tags: jquery

I see someone doing this but i cant,
That is possible to passing the **dataID** like this?

```
$(function() {
  $('.btnData').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataID = $(this).attr('val');
  });
  $('.tr-input').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var kolom1 = $(this).find('.td-input1').text(),
      kolom2 = $(this).find('.td-input2').text();
    $('.tdData1:eq(' + dataID + ')').val(kolom1);
    $('.tdData2:eq(' + dataID + ')').val(kolom2);
  });
});
```

Comment: `dataID` is var scoped to the click callback.  You need to declare that variable outside of the click handler if you want it to be more global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if whatever that person is doing works but I assume it does not unless there is another `dataID` variable that is for example a global variable and is defined somewhere within the code.

`var dataID = $(this).attr('val');` is scoped within the first function so if it is not declared elsewhere, it should not be accessible within the second function.

Comment: This states what the problem is.  It does not show how to fix it.  So it is not an answer.

Comment: The question is `That is possible to passing the dataID like this?`. As it is currently written the answer is `no` which is my answer. The fix is what you mentioned/what I also mention it works if the variable is global, accessible by both functions.

Comment: so the answer is no and that's impossible to passing varible like this, thank you bro